# The installer script is not running completely

Tags: magento-1.8, sql

I am trying to run a installer script but it always shows an error like 
The thing is I am running the fresh install but still it shows an error.

Here is my installer file.

```
    <?php
    $installer = $this;
    $installer->startSetup();
    $table = $installer->getConnection()
        ->newTable($installer->getTable('mycompany_mymodule_mymodel_media'))
        ->addColumn('media_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
            'identity' => true,
            'unsigned' => true,
            'nullable' => false,
            'primary' => true,
            ), 'Value ID')
        ->addColumn('mymodel_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
            'unsigned' => true,
            'nullable' => false,
            ), 'My model ID')
        ->addColumn('path', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255, array(
            ), 'Path')
        ->addColumn('label', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255, array(
            ), 'Label')
        ->addColumn('position', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
            'unsigned' => true,
            ), 'Position')
        ->addColumn('disabled', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT, null, array(
            'unsigned' => true,
            'nullable' => false,
            'default' => '0',
            ), 'Is Disabled')
        ->addColumn('creation_time', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP, null, array(
            ), 'Media Creation Time')
        ->addColumn('update_time', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP, null, array(
            ), 'Media Modification Time')
        ->addForeignKey($installer->getFkName('mycompany_mymodule_mymodel_media', 'mymodel_id', 'mycompany_mymodule_mymodel', 'mymodel_id'), 'mymodel_id', $installer->getTable('mycompany_mymodule_mymodel'), 'mymodel_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE, Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::ACTION_CASCADE)
        ->setComment('Mycompany mymodule media');
    $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
    /**
     * Add fields needed for a working media gallery.
     */
    $installer->getConnection()
        ->addColumn($installer->getTable('mycompany_mymodule_mymodel'), Mycompany_Mymodule_Model_Mymodel::BASE_IMAGE, array(
            'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            'length' => 255,
            'nullable' => true,
            'default' => Mycompany_Mymodule_Model_Mymodel::NO_SELECTION,
            'comment' => 'My model base image',
            )
        );
    $installer->getConnection()
        ->addColumn($installer->getTable('mycompany_mymodule_mymodel'), Mycompany_Mymodule_Model_Mymodel::BASE_IMAGE . '_label', array(
            'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            'length' => 255,
            'nullable' => true,
            'comment' => 'My model base image label',
            )
        );
    $installer->getConnection()
        ->addColumn($installer->getTable('mycompany_mymodule_mymodel'), Mycompany_Mymodule_Model_Mymodel::SMALL_IMAGE, array(
            'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            'length' => 255,
            'nullable' => true,
            'default' => Mycompany_Mymodule_Model_Mymodel::NO_SELECTION,
            'comment' => 'My moodel small image',
            )
        );
    $installer->getConnection()
        ->addColumn($installer->getTable('mycompany_mymodule_mymodel'), Mycompany_Mymodule_Model_Mymodel::SMALL_IMAGE . '_label', array(
            'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            'length' => 255,
            'nullable' => true,
            'comment' => 'My model small image label',
            )
        );
    $installer->getConnection()
        ->addColumn($installer->getTable('mycompany_mymodule_mymodel'), Mycompany_Mymodule_Model_Mymodel::THUMBNAIL, array(
            'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            'length' => 255,
            'nullable' => true,
            'default' => Mycompany_Mymodule_Model_Mymodel::NO_SELECTION,
            'comment' => 'My model thumbnail',
            )
        );
    $installer->getConnection()
        ->addColumn($installer->getTable('mycompany_mymodule_mymodel'), Mycompany_Mymodule_Model_Mymodel::THUMBNAIL . '_label', array(
            'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            'length' => 255,
            'nullable' => true,
            'comment' => 'My model thumbnail label',
            )
        );
    $installer->endSetup();
    ?>
```

**EDIT**

I do some debug and I found that the script is not running completely. It is not creating the tables and shows this error

```
    a:5:{i:0;s:222:"Error in file: "/var/www/magento/app/code/local/Mycompany/Mymodule/sql/mymodule_setup/mysql4-install-1.0.0.php" - SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento.mycompany_mymodule_mymodel' doesn't exist";i:1;s:884:"#0 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(421): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('install', '', '1.0.0')
#2 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(327): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_installResourceDb('1.0.0')
#3 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 /var/www/magento/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /var/www/magento/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:9:"/magento/";s:11:"script_name";s:18:"/magento/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Why it is showing `table not found` error, why script is not generating the table.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't another install script in this module that is creating the table?

Comment: Yeah this is the only script which is running,I again tried this, it doesn't run completely at once, I think there is an some error in the script but I cant find it. there are no errors shows in the browser

Answer (score 1):

Actually I do only see you create a new table `mycompany_mymodule_mymodel_media` but not `mycompany_mymodule_mymodel`?!

```
 $table = $installer->getConnection()
        ->newTable($installer->getTable('mycompany_mymodule_mymodel_media'))
```

In the `addForeignKey`-Method you reference to this table (`mycompany_mymodule_mymodel`) which is not present in the script above.